# Show/Hide a list of options depending if a checkbox is selected? Jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show-hide

Here is what the html looks like, I need help writing the jquery?
Initially the two divs will not be shown. If a user select the radio button "Bk", it will show "BreakdownList" div layer. If radio button "One" is select, the  "One-on-OneList" div layer is displayed. Users should be allow to toggle back and forth displaying either list.

```
<b> Monday, May 2, 2011 - Session Two </b>  <br>
<input name="Bk" type="radio" value="Break Out Session" >Break Out Session  <br>
<input name="One" type="radio" value="One-on-One Consulting Session" >One-on-One Consulting Session 
<div class="BreakdownList" style="display:none">
   <input name="1" type="radio" value="Session1">Session 1<br>
   <input name="2" type="radio" value="Session2">Session 2<br>
   <input name="2" type="radio" value="Session2">Session 3<br>
</div>
<div class="One-on-OneList" style="display:none">
    <input name="1" type="radio" value="One1">One on One 1<br>
   <input name="2" type="radio" value="One2">One on One 2<br>
   <input name="3" type="radio" value="One3">One on One 3<br>
</div>
```

Comment: your radio buttons need to have the same name to be grouped

Comment: use the radio as selector, use the :checked selector additionally and toggle() it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(':radio').on('click', function () {
    var name = $(this).prop('name');
    switch (name) {
    case 'Bk':
        $('div.BreakdownList').show();
        $('div.One-on-OneList').hide();
        break;
    case 'One':
        $('div.BreakdownList').hide();
        $('div.One-on-OneList').show();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the inputs should have the same name in order to let the user to choose between them, otherwise it's possible to select both simultaneously.
Ex:

```
<input class="bk" name"input_name" value="Break Out Session" />
```

In this case, I'd suggest you to use the input class on the click event and jquery toggle function, like this:

```
$('input.bk').click(function() {
    $('div.One-on-OneList').hide();
    $('div.BreakdownList').toggle();
});
$('input.one').click(function() {
    $('div.BreakdownList').hide();
    $('div.One-on-OneList').toggle();
});
```

I think this answer your question properly.